# Table: Extra text in new line

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an image.

[image: extra text in new]

Now, What my doubt is, I want the text below image to be in new line **if text is too long**. When I enter long text then the cell(td) is enlarged which I don't want to be.

So I want the extra text to be in new line. It should be limited to the width of image, after that extra text should be in new line.

I can't use **div** and **position** property. I have to use **table** tag only.

Image height should be same. I have tried using **word-wrap** , **white-space**, but image height gets differ for that.

```html
<table bgcolor="black" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border: thin white solid; " align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  >
                                                <tbody>

                                                <td align="center">
                                                    <table  style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="120">
                                                        <tbody><tr>
                                                            <td align="center" height="100" valign="top" width="100">
                                                                <p style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"><a class="modimg" style="text-decoration: none!important;" href="#"><img style=" border: 3px solid #ffcbbc ; outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" alt="" src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455301580.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a></p>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        </tbody></table>
                                                </td>


                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="h2" style=" font-weight: bold ;font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 10px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 0px;color:#ffffff;">
                                                       <p style="padding:0; margin:0;text-align: center;"> <span class="wrap_textbox">dsdsfsdfsdsfsdsdgsgdsdfsdfd</span></p>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="h2" style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 8px;text-align: center;color: #ffffff;">
                                                        <span class="wrap_textbox">Co-Founder at SeeFund</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                </tbody>

                                            </table>


                                            <!--Speaker 2-->

                                            <table  style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; margin: 0 auto; margin-left: 15px;  " align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                                                <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="center">
                                                        <table style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="120">
                                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                                <td align="center" height="100" valign="top" width="100">
                                                                    <p style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"><a class="modimg" style="text-decoration: none!important;" href="#"><img style=" border: 3px solid #ffcbbc ; outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" alt="" src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455949782.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a></p>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            </tbody></table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="h2" style=" font-weight: bold ;font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 10px;padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom: 0px;text-align: center;color:#ffffff; ">
                                                        <span class="wrap_textbox">Mr. R Chandrasekhar</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="h2" style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 8px;text-align: center;color: #ffffff;">
                                                        <span class="wrap_textbox">President of NASSCOM</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>



                                            <!--Speaker 3 -->

                                            <table  style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; margin: 0 auto;  margin-left: 15px;  " align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                                                <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="center">
                                                        <table style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="120">
                                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                                <td align="center" height="100" valign="top" width="100">
                                                                    <p style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"><a class="modimg" style="text-decoration: none!important;" href="#"><img style=" border: 3px solid #ffcbbc ; outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" alt="" src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455627060.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a></p>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            </tbody></table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="h2" style=" font-weight: bold ;font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 10px;padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom: 0px;text-align: center;color:#ffffff;">
                                                        <span class="wrap_textbox">Mr. Jay Panda</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="h2" style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 8px;text-align: center;color: #ffffff;">
                                                        <span class="wrap_textbox">Member of Parliament</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>


                                            <!--Speaker 4 -->


                                            <table  style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; margin: 0 auto;  margin-left: 15px;  " align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                                                <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="center">
                                                        <table style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="120">
                                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                                <td align="center" height="100" valign="top" width="100">
                                                                    <p style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"><a class="modimg" style="text-decoration: none!important;" href="#"><img style="border: 3px solid #ffcbbc; outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" alt="" src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455300140.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a></p>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            </tbody></table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="h2" style=" font-weight: bold ;font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 10px;padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom: 0px;text-align: center;color:#ffffff;">
                                                        <span class="wrap_textbox">Ms. Shazia Ilmi</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="h2" style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 8px;text-align: center;color: #ffffff;">
                                                        <span class="wrap_textbox">Spokesperson at BJP</span>
                                                    </td>
                                               </tr>
                                    </table>
```

Comment: Jeez you've used a lot of tables for a simple layout :| Any reason why you must use tables?

Comment: I want each td in different table. that's why. Or is there any simple way to do ?

Comment: You can add classes to `<td>` so it'd be `<td class="firstTable">` as an example. However, I have added a solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's what i done...

```html
<table bgcolor="black" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border: thin white solid; " align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  >
    <tbody>

    <td align="center">
        <table  style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="120">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td align="center" height="100" valign="top" width="100">
                    <p style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"><a class="modimg" style="text-decoration: none!important;" href="#"><img style=" border: 3px solid #ffcbbc ; outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" alt="" src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455301580.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody></table>
    </td>


    <tr>
        <td class="h2" style=" font-weight: bold ;font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 10px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 0px;color:#ffffff;">
            <p style="padding:0; margin:0;text-align: center; max-width:116px;"> <span class="wrap_textbox">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A consequuntur corporis, debitis dignissimos error fuga id inventore laudantium officiis quae quam, quia quos, repudiandae saepe sed sint tenetur? Doloribus, recusandae?</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="h2" style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 8px;text-align: center;color: #ffffff;">
            <span class="wrap_textbox">Co-Founder at SeeFund</span>
        </td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

Just add: `max-width:116px;` (or whatever you're happy with as a maximum width) and then it'll move its self on to a new line for you.

UPDATED

This is the line I added the styling to:

```
       <p style="padding:0; margin:0;text-align: center; max-width:116px;">
```

I'd highly advise putting these into CSS classes though and then into a stylesheet because if you ever wish to adjust the code in future you'll have to go into each file and adjust the `style=""` tag under each tag you've added it to.

Comment: Thank You. It worked as per my expectation. You saved my day.. Thanx a lot.. :)

Comment: No problem at all. As a bit of a pointer, review your code and look into stylesheets as I have mentioned and also 1 table rather than numerous. You'll have future issues if you decide to make the site responsive as an example.

Comment: I always write CSS in separate stylesheet and give reference to it. but I am making HTML emailer. so some email engine like Outlook , doesn't take external stylesheet. that's why I have to use **table** tag and stick to inline CSS .. :(

Comment: Ah I see. Not a problem then. My assumption was it was for a website as you didn't initially disclose it was for an email. :) Best of luck!

Comment: Do apologize for that.  however I always try to avoid inline CSS while development. but in this case I have to use it. Once again, Thank you.. :)